# How to attach a matTooltip to a disabled mat-tab?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to attach a matTooltip to a mat-icon in a disabled mat-tab but... it seems that this function is disabled when the mat-tab is disabled.
Has anybody got same problem ?

(I can't put the mat-tab in a div of course)

Thank you.

```
<mat-tab label="Tab 3" [disabled]="!picExist" >
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="picExist" matTooltip="See Pictures">photo_camera</mat-icon>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="!picExist" matTooltip="No picture!">add_a_photo</mat-icon>
    </ng-template>
    <div>The content</div>
</mat-tab>
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dou7pq)

Comment: Seems to work ok for me. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gzvkfc

Comment: Not for me!
I think the issue/problem is in the css.
I will ask the graphist... (but I don't understand how he managed to hide this matTooltip...)

Comment: The generated line is:
<mat-icon class="mat-icon material-icons" mattooltip="Pas encore de photo !" mattooltipposition="right" role="img" aria-hidden="true" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-5" cdk-describedby-host="" ng-reflect-position="right" ng-reflect-message="Pas encore de photo !">add_a_photo</mat-icon>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a disabled matTooltip in a `mat-tab` label you can't do it directly using

```
<mat-tab label="Pictures" matTooltip="See Pictures" disabled>
```

**First step**: You need to get the label out:

```
<mat-tab disabled>
   <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      Pictures
   </ng-template>
</mat-tab>
```

**Second step**: You need a HTML element as `ng-template` is not a DOM object and `matTooltip` need one:

```
<mat-tab disabled>
   <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <div matTooltip="See Pictures">
         Pictures
      </div>
   </ng-template>
</mat-tab>
```